# Passing Barcode Scanned Data to Second Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass the data I have received from scanning a barcode. I'm able to print the data using *JSON.stringify(data)* and the data is being passed but I just can't seem to display it.

Passing the data successfully with:

```
_handleBarCodeRead = data => {
Alert.alert(
  'Scan successful!',
  JSON.stringify(data)
);

const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
navigate('KnownProduct', {data})
};
```

Attempting to render the data on this page:

```
  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.data.toString}</Text>
        </View>
    );
```

I know the navigation works correctly because if I hard-code the value the screen does navigate after scanning a barcode and display the hard-coded value. However, I think I'm trying to call the data incorrectly with: *this.props.navigation.state.params.data.toString* but having no luck figuring out how to display the passed data.

Any react native experts able to help a newbie?

OK.... So I figured it out... thanks to one commenter who pointed out I should pass the data like so:

```
navigate('KnownProduct', {data: data})
```

And then what was missing in the redirection page was:

```
<Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.data.data}</Text>
```

data.data got me!

Comment: I believe you need to pass a name for your datas, like so: `navigate('KnownProduct', { data: data });`

Comment: What about `toString()` instead of simply `toString`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
navigate('KnownProduct', {data:JSON.stringify(data)})
```

AND

```
<Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.data}</Text>
```

Comment: So I tried this and the error I get passed was:

    Invariant violation: Objects are not valid as React child (found: object with keys 
   {type, data}. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can you console the data and show me? apparently data is an object I thought it was a string

Comment: Hi Miguel, I managed to figure it out... slightly different from your approach but I specifically wanted one of the parameters in the object and using data.data did the trick for me. :) (Check the bottom of the question for what I did)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 navigate('KnownProduct', {data:data.data})
<Text>{this.props.navigation.getParam('data')}</Text>
```